# Unable to get PDF with images from Prawn PDF in a Node.js webapp

Tags: node.js, prawn

Am using Prawn PDF in a node.js webapp to generate PDF on the fly and send it back to the user. It works fine as long as there are no images in the PDF doc. The moment I include an image (png or jpeg) in the pdf, the spawned node child process never gets the 'exit' message.

The same ruby script outputs a pdf with images as expected when run in the shell. Somehow the image data seems to get messed up when sent over stdout! Do I have to escape it?

Thanks,
mano

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('ruby', ['print_scripts/print.rb', doc_id]);
var pdf = '';

child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    if(data.toString() != 'ERROR'){
    pdf += data;
    }
});
child.on('exit', function(code){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    if(code == 0){
    res.send(pdf);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to call the Ruby script?

Comment: @robertklep: Updated with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple test I did, `exit` is called even before `data` is called. That's probably related to this notice: ["Note that the child process stdio streams might still be open."](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) (which could mean that there's still data left in internal buffers that needs to be read).

When you're not using images, the output might be small enough to fit in a single buffer so the problem doesn't appear. Instead of `exit` you should probably catch the `close` event instead.

There's also an issue of implicit conversion to string in your code (`pdf += data`), which could cause problems as well.

I think this will work:

```
var chunks = [];

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  // insert error check here...
  chunks.push(data);
});
child.on('close', function() {
  var pdf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  res.send(pdf);
});
```

Comment: You nailed it :-) Even after listening to 'close' I got a pdf but without an image. But after using Buffer.concat it works as expected. Thanks a ton.